# State province shows duplicate entries

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am working with magento 1.9.2.2 and the  customer registration page shows duplicate state/province names suggestions . 
I checked the database. Only single entry is present there in both

1. directory_country_region
2. directory_country_region_name

Still why registration page shows duplicate ? any clue ?

Comment: You should post a screenshot.  I can think of two answers right off the bat.  First answer is that you have two blocks rendering the same content.  (Ie, two layout updates)  Two, you have invalid html.

Comment: @df2k2 any clue how to find those malicious blocks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adding the list of states in India to Magento

**I have tested this and worked for me on my server.** 
Please open your php my admin and Please truncate table and run following:

```
INSERT INTO directory_country_region VALUES
(NULL , "IN", "Andaman and Nicobar","Andaman and Nicobar"),
(NULL , "IN", "Andhra Pradesh","Andhra Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Arunachal Pradesh","Arunachal Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Assam","Assam"),
(NULL , "IN", "Bihar","Bihar"),
(NULL , "IN", "Chandigarh","Chandigarh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Chhattisgarh","Chhattisgarh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Dadra and Nagar Haveli","Dadra and Nagar Haveli"),
(NULL , "IN", "Daman and Diu","Daman and Diu"),
(NULL , "IN", "Delhi","Delhi"),
(NULL , "IN", "Goa","Goa"),
(NULL , "IN", "Gujarat","Gujarat"),
(NULL , "IN", "Haryana","Haryana"),
(NULL , "IN", "Himachal Pradesh","Himachal Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Jammu and Kashmir","Jammu and Kashmir"),
(NULL , "IN", "Jharkhand","Jharkhand"),
(NULL , "IN", "Karnataka","Karnataka"),
(NULL , "IN", "Kerala","Kerala"),
(NULL , "IN", "Lakshadweep","Lakshadweep"),
(NULL , "IN", "Madhya Pradesh","Madhya Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Maharashtra","Maharashtra"),
(NULL , "IN", "Manipur","Manipur"),
(NULL , "IN", "Meghalaya","Meghalaya"),
(NULL , "IN", "Mizoram","Mizoram"),
(NULL , "IN", "Nagaland","Nagaland"),
(NULL , "IN", "Orissa","Orissa"),
(NULL , "IN", "Pondicherry","Pondicherry"),
(NULL , "IN", "Punjab","Punjab"),
(NULL , "IN", "Rajasthan","Rajasthan"),
(NULL , "IN", "Sikkim","Sikkim"),
(NULL , "IN", "Tamil Nadu","Tamil Nadu"),
(NULL , "IN", "Tripura","Tripura"),
(NULL , "IN", "Uttar Pradesh","Uttar Pradesh"),
(NULL , "IN", "Uttaranchal","Uttaranchal"),
(NULL , "IN", "West Bengal","West Bengal");
```

INSERT INTO `directory_country_region_name` (`locale` ,`region_id` ,`name` )
    SELECT 'en_US', tmp.region_id, tmp.default_name FROM `directory_country_region`
        AS tmp WHERE tmp.country_id='IN';

I hope it will help to you. http://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2015/12/adding-list-of-states-in-india-to.html

Comment: this is not relevant for the question. i asked why duplicate suggestions are coming on address / customer creation pages of onepage

Comment: plz share screenshot

Comment: This answer is not at all relavant to OP's question.  Please do not copy an answer from somewhere and paste it here.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara please see screen shot https://postimg.org/image/lhrf6tszn/

Comment: @RajeevKTomy have some clue to this error ?

Comment: @Bineesh This problem is mainly happends due to the duplicated entries in the given tables in your qeustion. Other than this, without see relevant codes, I am helpless on this. But this solution is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy, you dont know whether i copied or not right. but you commented simply as dont copy and paste. Ok. Good.

Comment: @Bineesh, Actually bro, what i want to tell you is, please truncate those all before entries and reassign the state values through myadmin

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara If you didn't copy that from somewhere else, then it is good for you. But I am sure I see the same answer multiple places and that is why I commented on your answer. I dont have time to do investigation on this and I really appreciate your valuable time and effort you put forward for Magento Community. But clearly this answer has no relavance to this answer.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy, Hey bro, plz dont mind, just i pointed that only, dont mind. actually i understood like that, thats y i posted. Actually i have already tried and succeed. u dont mind

Comment: @RajeevKTomy thank your for your reply. But i already made sure that no duplicate entries are in database. Anyways i look into other ways to solve it.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy technically Tej was not giving relevant answer. But what  happened is his solution seemed working. Thank you Rajeev Thank you Tej

Comment: @Bineesh if that helps, please feel free to accept his answer. I request Teja to update his answer with the key point "please truncate table and reupload the code"

Comment: @RajeevKTomy and Bineesh thank you for both of you.

Comment: @Bineesh, if my answer is helpful to you please upvote and accept my answer. Best of luck Bro.